Hiding the Voronoi texture from the bottom of my chocolate chip cookie
I'm making a chocolate chip cookie in blender using two Principled BDSF materials, one for the cookie material and one for the chocolate chip material. I'm using Voronoi texture and color ramp and mix shader to determine where the chocolate chips appear. The problem is that the chocolate chips appear on the bottom and sides of my cookie, which I don't want. How do I solve this? Can I make some sort of mask and paint only the top of my cookie or something similar?



You could add a "Geometry" node, take the "normal" from this node, separate Z, use a math node to compare this z greater than something around 0.5 and use it as fac to mix. (In short, this considers only  faces pointing up wards with some tolerance given by the limit you gave.

@DanielMöller I tried playing around with what you recommended but I cant seem to get the right results. Where do i put the result of the greater than node, because my fac in mix shader is already occupied by the color ramp.

@DanielMöller I solved the issue by putting a multiply node between the mix shader and color ramp, and connected the greater than and color ramp to the multiply and connected the result to fac. Thanks for your help!
